# How to force input and array of vectors

Tags: vector, vhdl

Does anyone know how to input or force in an array of vectors? I believe it was like that but it is not working.

```
--------- Test Bench ---------------

LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.mypackage2.all;

ENTITY test_bench IS
PORT (H   : in  enter_vector := ("1100","0011","1111","1101","1100","0011","1111","1101","1100","0011","1111","1101","1100","0011","1111","1101");
      L   : in  enter_vector := ("1100","0011","1111","1101","1100","0011","1111","1101","1100","0011","1111","1101","1100","0011","1111","1101");
        X   : out integer);
END entity;
ARCHITECTURE comportamento OF test_bench IS



COMPONENT MUX is
    Port ( SEL : in  STD_LOGIC;
           H   : in  enter_vector;
           L   : in  enter_vector;
           X   : out enter_vector;
              Sinal: out std_logic -- it is 1 if H and 0 if L
              );
END COMPONENT;


COMPONENT choose is
    Port ( SEL : in  STD_LOGIC;
           E   : in  enter_vector;
           X    : out integer);
END COMPONENT;

signal VC : enter_vector;
signal sin,sel: std_logic; 



BEGIN

m:  MUX PORT MAP (sel,H,L,VC,sin);
cc: choose PORT MAP (sin,VC,X);




END comportamento;

------- Type Created-----

    library IEEE; 
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all; 

    package mypackage2 is 

              type enter_vector is array (15 to 0) of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); -- array of bytes 

    end mypackage2; 


    package body mypackage2 is 

    end mypackage2;
```

Comment: Besides declaring type enter_vector to define a null array (IEEE Std 1078-2008 5.3.2.2 Index constraints and discrete ranges) with `to` instead of `downto` your question does not demonstrate a problem. An actual (6.5.6.3 Port clauses) for a port would require the same type. Presumably your code would analyze while `H` and `L` carry no information. Your question does not provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
type enter_vector is array (15 to 0) of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
--                              ^
--                              |
```

you needed this:

```
type enter_vector is array (15 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
--                                ^
--                                |
```

This is a nasty "gotcha" in VHDL. It is not an error to use `to` instead of `downto`, but you end up with an array with length 0. This then usually causes some other error somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Ok but its is not my problem. My problem is in this line:

Comment: H   : in  enter_vector := ("1100","0011","1111","1101","1100","0011","1111","1101","1100","0011","1111","1101","1100","0011","1111","1101");
      L   : in  enter_vector := ("1100","0011","1111","1101","1100","0011","1111","1101","1100","0011","1111","1101","1100","0011","1111","1101")

Comment: @MatheusSasso As I said above, the error message throws out that line, but your problem is in your package. I corrected it and it compiles fine: [https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2upq](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2upq).

Comment: What error message? Not presented by the OP or you.

Comment: @user1155120 `COMP96 ERROR COMP96_0127: "Improper aggregate length. Expected length is 0." "testbench.vhd" 7 33`

Comment: None of this shows up in your answer or the question. Another tool might show an error for `L` as well. `type enter_vector is array (15 to 0) of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);` is a legal declaration defining a type that is a null array with an element subtype of std_logic_vector. The aggregate default expressions for ports `H` and 'L` aren't of the type `enter_vector` ( 6.5.2 para 7, 9.3.3.1, 5.3.2.2 para 2, 12.5)  without changing the type declaration. [Sand, meet pearl](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/).

Comment: @user1155120 I think you're splitting hairs. The user asked why his code didn't compile thinking, quite understandably, that the error was in the line indicated by the error message. In fact, the problem was somewhere else and I fixed that. More usefully for subsequent readers, the error is (a) common and (b) nasty. So much so, that I particularly draw the attention of my students to it.